# Alpine.js - Passing javascript variable to Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a simple Livewire component called `index.blade.php`. All it does currently is render below:

```html
<div x-data>
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify($store.data.entities)"></div>
</div>
```

The data above comes from my `app.js` file:

```js
Alpine.store('data', {
    entities: [{'type': 'order', 'reference': '12345678'}],
})
```

Thus in my component, the following will be rendered:

```
[{"type":"order","reference":"12345678"}]
```

This works fine. However, I want to pass the value of `$store.data.entities` to another Livewire component:

```
<div x-data>
    <div x-text="JSON.stringify($store.data.entities)"></div>
    <!-- Show specific entity -->
    @livewire('show-entity', [])
</div>
```

However, I am not sure how I can pass the `$store.data.entities` as a parameter to `show-entity` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Livewire 2 or above, you can use [`$wire`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#interacting-with-livewire-from-alpine).

Move the div *inside* your Livewire component, then simply:

```html
<div x-data="{'entities': JSON.stringify($store.data.entities)}" x-text="entities" x-init="$wire.set('entities', entities')"></div>
```

Upon init of Alpine, it should set the Livewire variable (called `$entities` in this example) to the value of your JSON.